# Django error message "Add a related_name argument to the definition"

Tags: django

```
D:\zjm_code\basic_project>python manage.py syncdb
Error: One or more models did not validate:
topics.topic: Accessor for field 'content_type' clashes with related field 'Cont
entType.topic_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'content_t
ype'.
topics.topic: Accessor for field 'creator' clashes with related field 'User.crea
ted_topics'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'creator'.
topics.topic: Reverse query name for field 'creator' clashes with related field
'User.created_topics'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'creato
r'.
topicsMap.topic: Accessor for field 'content_type' clashes with related field 'C
ontentType.topic_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'conten
t_type'.
topicsMap.topic: Accessor for field 'creator' clashes with related field 'User.c
reated_topics'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'creator'.
topicsMap.topic: Reverse query name for field 'creator' clashes with related fie
ld 'User.created_topics'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'cre
ator'.
```

Comment: If you don't know what a "related_name" argument is, the error message instructions aren't very useful. The Django "Related objects" docs don't necessarily help; they don't define a related_name nor make it clear that you can invent any value you want for your related_name.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You have a number of foreign keys which django is unable to generate unique names for.

You can help out by adding "related_name" arguments to the foreignkey field definitions in your models.
Eg:

```
content_type = ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='topic_content_type')
```

See here for more.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: or just `related_name='+'`

Comment: @HuckleberryFinn, what does `+` do?

Comment: `related_name='+'` does suppress the error but note its purpose - to opt out of the "backward" link.  IE: `fooo_set` usage on a foreign instance will be unable to find the instances here which are using it.

Answer (score 87):

Example:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User')
    editor = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User')
```

This will cause the error, because Django tries to automatically create a backwards relation for instances of `accounts.User` for each foreign key relation to user like `user.article_set`.  This default method is ambiguous.  Would `user.article_set.all()` refer to the user's articles related by the author field, or by the editor field?

Solution:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name='author_article_set')
    editor = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name='editor_article_set')
```

Now, for an instance of user `user`, there are two different manager methods:

1. `user.author_article_set` — `user.author_article_set.all()` will return a Queryset of all Article objects that have author == user
2. `user.editor_article_set` — `user.editor_article_set.all()` will return a Queryset of all Article objects that have editor == user

---

**Note**:
This is an old example — `on_delete` is now another required argument to `models.ForeignKey`.  Details at [What does on_delete do on Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models)

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a dramatically better answer than the accepted. Thank you for the clean explanation and example!

Comment: If you could elaborate on the `on_delete` argument as well, that would be good, @MarkCharkerian

Comment: @NeilG I added a link.

Answer (score 14):

"If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the source model name, lowercased."

But if you have more than one foreign key in a model, django is unable to generate unique names for foreign-key manager.
You can help out by adding "related_name" arguments to the foreignkey field definitions in your models.

See here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Half the battle is understanding what the error message means. I found this simple explanation (with the link) very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If your models are inheriting from the same parent model, you should set a unique `related_name` in the parent's **ForeignKey**. For example:

`author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related')`

It's better explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#abstract-related-name)

Answer (score 2):

If your models are inheriting from the same parent model, you should set a unique related_name in the parent's ForeignKey. For example:

```
author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related')
```

It's better explained in th

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to code a solution for a table that would pull names of football teams from the same table.
My table looked like this:

```
hometeamID = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
awayteamID = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

making the below changes solved my issue:

```
hometeamID = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='home_team')
awayteamID = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='away_team')
```

Answer (score 0):

But in my case i am create a separate app for some functionality with same model name and field ( copy/paste ;) ) that's because of this type of error occurs i am just deleted the old model and code will work fine
May be help full for beginners like me :)

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an ultimate answer for the question, however for someone it may solve the problem.
I got the same error in my project after checking out a really old commit (going to detached head state) and then getting the code base back up to date. Solution was to delete all *.pyc files in the project.

Answer (score -3):

Do as the error message instructs you to:

> Add a related_name argument to the
>   definition for 'creator'.

Comment: Yeah, great, I'll do then `related_name="foobar"`? Is that ok? Maybe! How do I know? I don't!