# Django Error, What should i do?

Tags: django, django-models

shop.category: Reverse query name for field 'parent_category' clashes with related field 'Category.category'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'parent_category'.

django version 1.3.1
python version 2.7.2

Comment: I think you should add a related_name argument to the definition for 'parent_category'.

Comment: Can you print the model's description?

Comment: Hm, isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606194/django-error-what-should-i-do) your question? If not, interesting coincidence. :-) Anyway, your question is answered there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a related_name argument to the appropriate field in your model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Yup, just add a unique related_name argument in your clashing field(s).