# After upgrading to Django1.7 related_names throw error

Tags: python, django, django-models

Every thing was working fine with Django1.6, but when upgraded to Django1.7 it showed "App registry not ready", so I changed get_user_model() to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL in my models.

```
class MyModel(models.Model, SomeMixin):
    content = models.TextField()
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                              related_name='name1')
    note = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel, related_name='name2')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now, on starting the server I get following error messages.

ERRORS:
apps.MyModel.posted_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'model_field' clashes with reverse accessor for 'model_field'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'model_field' or 'model_field'.

Changing related is not the best way I can go for, as changing related name involves change to a lot of code. What am I missing here? What should be I looking for? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the related names clash, then you can't really do anything except add or change `related_name`, even if that involves changing a lot of code. 

It's not clear what the clash is, because your question is a mixture of actual model names e.g. `Comment` and made-up names like `MyModel`.

Comment: This is just an example of one of my models and I get the same error for most of the models. I tried to change related names and that seem to fix the issue except for User.groups(which I cannot change). Any work arounds you suggest?

Comment: As I said before, I don't think your example code gives enough information to see what the problem is. Hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `related_name='+'` for one of the fields solved a similar issue for me.  See the comments to the accept answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606194/django-error-message-add-a-related-name-argument-to-the-definition)