# Deleting related objects deletes the ForeignKey object

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.7

I have the following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
      user_question = models.ForeignKey(UserQuestion)

class Question(models.Model):
      text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserQuestion(models.Model):
      answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='questions')
```

When I run the query below the user model is also deleted

```
user.questions.all().delete()
```

Is there any way to delete the questions without deleting the user?

I tried iterating over the questions and that didn't work

```
questions = user.questions.all()
for an in questions:
     answer.delete()
```

I thought the queryset was lazy so maybe I needed to evaluate it before deleting so I printed it and this did not work.

```
print questions
questions.delete()
```

I know that making the ForeignKey nullable would provide me with methods like clear and remove but I did not want to do this because I did not want any orphaned user questions.

I updated the ForeignKey as follows

```
class UserQuestion(models.Model):
  answer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='questions', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` but when I ran the query below The question model was still deleted.

```
user.questions.all().delete()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

untested, but should work.

Your issue is a DB related issue, when deleting a foreignkey the DB will try to delete the related row.

Read more on the other options on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models).

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. I think models.SET_NULL requires the field to be nullable and on_delete only seems to refer to one side of the relationship. So when I delete a question I can keep the answers but my problem is that when I delete the answers I want to keep the question.

Comment: deleting the question and keeping the answer is the default behavior, I forgot that the field need a `null=True`, updated the answer. This make sense because, when deleting an answer the foreign key field should be null

Comment: Also don't forget to run `makemigration` and `migrate`

Comment: I really didnt want to set the field to be nullable because I didn't like the idea of orphaned answers (because answers mean nothing without a question) but I set null=True and on_delete=models.SET_NULL. The result was still that the question was deleted. I made sure to run makemigrations and migrate

Comment: Your answer worked for me. I wasn't working with question and answer models those were just an analogy for more complex model that I was working on. I was looking at the wrong relationship and thats why my models were getting deleted.