# What does adding on_delete to models.py do, and what should I put in it?

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

The text of this answer is provided in the "duplicate question," though this goes into much more detail than any answers provided there.

FYI, the on_delete parameter in models is backwards from what it sounds like.  You put "on_delete" on a Foreign Key (FK) on a model to tell django what to do if the FK entry that you are pointing to on your record is deleted.  The options our shop have used the most are PROTECT, CASCADE, and SET_NULL. Here are the basic rules I have figured out:

1. Use PROTECT when your FK is pointing to a look-up table that really shouldn't be changing and that *certainly* should not cause your table to change.  If anyone tries to delete an entry on that look-up table, PROTECT prevents them from deleting it if it is tied to any records.  It also prevents django from deleting *your* record just because it deleted an entry on a look-up table.  This last part is critical.  *If someone were to delete the gender "Female" from my Gender table, I CERTAINLY would NOT want that to instantly delete any and all people I had in my Person table who had that gender.*
2. Use CASCADE when your FK is pointing to a "parent" record.  So, if a Person can have many PersonEthnicity entries (he/she can be American Indian, Black, and White), and that Person *is* deleted, I really *would* want any "child" PersonEthnicity entries to be deleted.  They are irrelevant without the Person.
3. Use SET_NULL when you *do* want people to be allowed to delete an entry on a look-up table, but you still want to preserve your record.  For example, if a Person can have a HighSchool, but it doesn't really matter to me if that high-school goes away on my look-up table, I would say "on_delete=SET_NULL."  This would leave my Person record out there; it just would just set the high-school FK on my Person to null.  Obviously, you will have to allow null=True on that FK.

Here is an example of a model that does all three things:

```
class PurchPurchaseAccount(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(PurchPurchase, null=True, db_column='purchase', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # If "parent" rec gone, delete "child" rec!!!
    paid_from_acct = models.ForeignKey(PurchPaidFromAcct, null=True, db_column='paid_from_acct', blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT) # Disallow lookup deletion & do not delete this rec.
    _updated = models.DateTimeField()
    _updatedby = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, db_column='_updatedby', blank=True, related_name='acctupdated_by', on_delete=models.SET_NULL) # Person records shouldn't be deleted, but if they are, preserve this PurchPurchaseAccount entry, and just set this person to null.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.paid_from_acct.display)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'purch_purchase_account'
```

As a last tidbit, did you know that if you *don't* specify on_delete (or didn't), the default behavior is CASCADE?  This means that if someone deleted a gender entry on your Gender table, any Person records with that gender were also deleted!

I would say, "If in doubt, set on_delete=models.PROTECT."  Then go test your application.  You will quickly figure out which FKs should be labeled the other values without endangering any of your data.

Also, it is worth noting that on_delete=CASCADE is actually not added to any of your migrations, if that is the behavior you are selecting. I guess this is because it is the default, so putting on_delete=CASCADE is the same thing as putting nothing.