# how to resolve error in Django models.py?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I am new to Django and was trying to make a Django project inside the virtualenv to learn but getting following error on `python manage.py make migrations`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 21, in 
>       main()
>     File "manage.py", line 17, in main
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File
>  "/home/suraj/Documents/my_projects/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File
>  "/home/suraj/Documents/my_projects/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 357, in execute
>       django.setup()
>     File
>  "/home/suraj/Documents/my_projects/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File
>  "/home/suraj/Documents/my_projects/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
>       app_config.import_models()
>     File
>  "/home/suraj/Documents/my_projects/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>     File
>  "/home/suraj/Documents/my_projects/django_project/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>     File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
>     File "", line 971, in _find_and_load
>     File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>     File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>     File "", line 678, in exec_module
>     File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>     File
>  "/home/suraj/Documents/my_projects/django_project/web_board/boards/models.py", line 11, in 
>       class Topic(models.Model):
>     File
>  "/home/suraj/Documents/my_projects/django_project/web_board/boards/models.py", line 14, in Topic
>       board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics')
>   TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Comment: on_delete is required in Django 2.0+  previously it defaulted to CASCADE.  Older tutorials may be missing that piece of information

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are creating a model with **Foreign key**.

When you create such model, you must specify what to happen when the record in foreign key table is deleted.

Just add what should happen when the record is deleted using `on_delete` parameter for that column in the model and you should be good.

```
board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics', on_delete=**what_you_want_to_do_when_parent_record_gets_deleted**)
```

[what does on_delete do on Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models)