# Django delete all M2M related objects on main object delete

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

```
class Project(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   project_results_m2m =  models.ManyToManyField(Project_Results,blank=True)

   def delete_all(self): 
        pass ### TO BE ADDED FROM ANSWERS
```

- signal

```
@receiver(post_delete,sender=Project) 
def delete_project_signal(sender,instance,created=False,**kwargs):
    if created is False:
       instance.delete_all()
```

```
p = Project.objects.get(id=1)
p.delete()
```

- Once above `delete()` triggered on Project object  `1` then the signal would execute `delete_all` function.

Now I would like to **delete** all objects of `Project_Results` related to `project_results_m2m` for Project object `1`.

How do I achieve it in a **safe manner** while deleting, either with signals or without signals?

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models

Comment: Is there a reason Project_Results don't have a ForeignKey pointing to Project?

Comment: Question is related to M2M, if it would foriengkey then `models.cascade` would do it by  default

Comment: Can a `Project_Results` be linked to multiple `Project`s? If so, do you still want to delete it when *any* of its `Project`s are deleted, or only when *all* of its `Project`s are deleted? If not, then you should almost certainly be using a ForeignKey instead of M2M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to use [**`pre_delete`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-delete) signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Project, dispatch_uid='project_delete_all')
def delete_all_instances(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
   instance.project_results_m2m.all().delete()
```