# Correct on_delete option

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a `Car` model and a `CarImage` model and the `CarImage` model uses a foreign key to relate to a `Car` object. If I set `on_delete=models.CASCADE` when I delete an image will that also delete the `Car` object that `CarImage` is linked to?

**models.py**

```
class Car(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)


class CarImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    model = models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to='main.Car')
```

Comment: When you delete CarImage instance, Car instance linked to it still will exist. When you delete Car instance, all CarImages connected to it will be deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does on\_delete do on Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models)