# What is the expected behaviour when a model has two foreign keys with different on_delete constraints?

Tags: django

Let's say I have this model:

```
class UserBook(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Where the user is only allowed to borrow 1 book at a time. I want instances of this model to get deleted if the user gets deleted, but I don't want them to get deleted if a book gets deleted (by mistake, just a precaution).

What is the expected behaviour when a user gets deleted using the above constraint? I'm getting:

> Cannot delete some instances of model 'UserBook' because they are
> referenced through a protected foreign key

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I tried to delete UserBook on `pre_save`/`post_save` signals with the `User` as a sender but neither worked.

Comment: there may be another model having a foreign key to `UserBook` with `on_delete=models.PROTECT`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Just double checked and that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is done through `RESTRICT` option.

Here is an example from the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.RESTRICT)

They also use `models.ForeignKey` and not `models.OneToOne`

This post may also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/38389488/13482680

Comment: `RESTRICT` indeed solves this. Unfortunately it's fairly new (>= 3.1) so can't use it without an upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: I used the opportunity to upgrade Django and this is now working perfectly as I wanted. Thanks again!