# Django set relation between two models

Tags: python, django

I want to save my custom Model as Field in another Model as shown below.
It's normal when I create and work with them during one session.
But when I start a new session Django loads the Game model with player1 and player2 that have a null id.

Here example of my code

```
class Player(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Game(models.Model):
    player1 = Player()
    player2 = Player()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69632633/django-set-relation-between-two-models#comment123080508_69632755). I think this is what you are going for.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Game(models.Model):
    player1 = models.OneToOneField(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='p1_game')
    player2 = models.OneToOneField(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='p2_game')
```

Comment: Those related names are really bad. Name them anything that indicates you are accessing a `Game` instance!

Comment: @user2390182 How about `p1_game`?

Comment: Yeah, that's much better. See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), django's way of implementing a [many-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

```
class Game(models.Model):
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="p1game")
    player2 = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="p2game")
```

Don't forget to `makemigrations` and `migrate`!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to have relationships many-to-one. Also, your variant wouldn't work, because player.game_set.create() - it becomes uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a foreign key:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Game(models.Model):
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player2 = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

See [What does on_delete do on Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models) for information about the `on_delete` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But here I would like to implement a one-to-one relationship. If it is possible.

Comment: Also, this will result in clashes between player1 and player2. For example 
player = Player()
player.game_set.create() - it become uncertain

Comment: I added related names to disambiguate the reverse access. A one-to-one means that every player can be in at most two games. Once as player1 and once as player2. Is that what you are aiming for?