# How to create a class in django which will be deleted when the element in another class is deleted

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django please help me with this doubt .How to create a class in django which will be deleted when the element in other class is deleted ?

Comment: What have you tried to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does on\_delete do on Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388423/what-does-on-delete-do-on-django-models)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) on your `ForeignKey` filed

for more explanation, look [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/django-on_delete)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```py
class Company:
     name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=150)
    
class Car:
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Whenever company is deleted. All the cars with that company will also get deleted. If you do `on_delete=models.PROTECT` it will prevent deletion of records because it's protected.