# How to change `related_name` field of model after migration in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Initially I created a model as shown here:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creater")
    # rest of the fields below
```

Notice, creator as a field with `ForeignKey` relation with `related_name` as **`creater`** which is actually a spelling mistake which I made. Then I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands and it went well.

After that I realised that I need to correct the spelling and I changed it accordingly as shown here:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creator")
    # rest of the fields below
```

Now again to incorporate these changes I ran the above two command but when I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` command I got following error:

```
(django_env) dayanandghelaro@A006-00592 fiverr_backend % python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
gigs.Gig.creator: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'gigs.Gig.creator' clashes with reverse accessor for 'orders.Order.creator'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'gigs.Gig.creator' or 'orders.Order.creator'.
gigs.Gig.creator: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'gigs.Gig.creator' clashes with reverse query name for 'orders.Order.creator'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'gigs.Gig.creator' or 'orders.Order.creator'.
orders.Order.creator: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'orders.Order.creator' clashes with reverse accessor for 'gigs.Gig.creator'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'orders.Order.creator' or 'gigs.Gig.creator'.
orders.Order.creator: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'orders.Order.creator' clashes with reverse query name for 'gigs.Gig.creator'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'orders.Order.creator' or 'gigs.Gig.creator'.
(django_env) dayanandghelaro@A006-00592 fiverr_backend %
```

If you want to see **error** in image then click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gLx5.png)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606194/django-error-message-add-a-related-name-argument-to-the-definition/2607848) might be helpful

Comment: Your `Gig` model also uses `creator` as a related name for user. Try to change them to `created_orders` and `created_gigs` so you can access them from users like `user.created_orders.all()` and `user.created_gigs.all()` respectively

Comment: Dear @Rustam, I am sorry images was not attached properly so I edited the whole text here and formatted accordingly. Can you please tell me how to get it fixed now?