# in django two fields with foreign keys from one model to link two fields from another model

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I have a "ModelVoiture" model with a foreign key "type_carburant" field and I can access the "typeCarburant" field of the "Carburant" model. I need to access another field of the same model "Carburant", the field "prixCarburant" from the model "ModelVoiture" but if I add the line

```
prixCarburant = models.ForeignKey(Carburant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i have this error

```
coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.prixCarburant: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Carburant.modelvoiture_set' for 'coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.prixCarburant' clashes with reverse accessor for 'coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.typeCarburant'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.prixCarburant' or 'coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.typeCarburant'.
coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.typeCarburant: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Carburant.modelvoiture_set' for 'coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.typeCarburant' clashes with reverse accessor for 'coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.prixCarburant'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.typeCarburant' or 'coutcarbur.ModelVoiture.prixCarburant'.
```

my code in coutcarbur/models.py

```
class MarqueVoiture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Carburant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prixCarburant = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    typeCarburant = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ModelVoiture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    consolitre = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    prixCarburant = models.ForeignKey(Carburant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    typeCarburant = models.ForeignKey(Carburant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    marque = models.ForeignKey(MarqueVoiture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

how to implement related_name function in template to solve this problem.
I must surely revise the diagram of my models?

thanks for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398542/16537039

Comment: thank , i try this solution  in "ModelVoiture" model : prixCarburant = models.ForeignKey(Carburant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='prixCarburant_carburant')
    typeCarburant = models.ForeignKey(Carburant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='typeCarburant_carburant')  but now the foreign key in "prixCarburant" field  have same target of "typeCarburant"  of "Carburant" model

Comment: finally I realized that I do not need to link the "TypeCarburant" fields of the "Carburant"  model to "modelVoiture" models. not thought enough about the design of the models. sorry for the disturbance. Anyway, if anyone has a solution to the original question that would be a bonus.