# How to repeat a Foreign Key Model, on multiple fields in another Model ? + Django

Tags: python, django

I want to build Trip.Model, with multiple Hotel.Model assignments, each under a different field name. Example(_pb, _hv, _nl)

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    hotel_pb = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    hotel_hv = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    hotel_nl = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
```

How do I achieve this without creating multiple Hotel.Model ?

- I have tried using the same Foreignkey, but throws error.

  `Reverse accessor 'Activity.trip_set' for 'gobasic.Trip.acitivity_3' clashes with reverse accessor for 'gobasic.Trip.acitivity_1'. HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'gobasic.Trip.acitivity_3' or 'gobasic.Trip.acitivity_1'`

Comment: I am not pretty sure what was your intention but it seems to me that Many to many relation could resolve your issue: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @SerSergious precise fix on related_name found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606194/django-error-message-add-a-related-name-argument-to-the-definition

My code fixed as such: 

```class Trip(models.Model):
    hotel_pb = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='pb_hotel_set', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    hotel_hv = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='hv_hotel_set', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    hotel_nl = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='nl_hotel_set', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)```

Comment: Please edit your question and add this answer with correct formating, of course if it works for you.

Comment: I fixed the question, thanks for the suggestion. Stackoverflow won't let me answer for now :(

Comment: So the code from the comment works or not?

Answer (score 1):

Use `related_name`, see below.

```
hotel_pb = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name = 'hotel_pb', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    hotel_hv = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name = 'hotel_hv',on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    hotel_nl = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name = 'hotel_nl',on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
```